# Pandas series replace empty string values in a column with nan

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, nan

I have the following "TL" column in a pandas dataframe:

```
ID  TL     
1   alfdjalk
2   jafd;jsa
3
4
5   ajf;dlka;fd
6   ajdf;k
```

Right now the TL has dtype of object.  The blanks are empty strings.

I want to make the empty strings nulls instead.  So I tried the following code:

```
df_EVENT5_28['TL'] = df_EVENT5_28['TL'].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()).replace('', np.nan)
```

But I'm getting the error below: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried: `df = df.replace('', np.nan)` ?

Comment: @jpp that is perfect, put it as an answer...  It may not help the OP anymore, but it might help others.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. The other questions are about an entire dataframe. This question is about a specific column. That's a significant difference. For a column, you can just use `col[col == ''] = pd.NA`.

Comment: To add to @jpp 's answer: To change just the one column `TL`: `import numpy as np` and `df['TL'] = df['TL'].replace('', np.nan)`. You can check the correctness by `df['TL'].isnull()` (Unfortunately the question is closed now and answers cannot be added.)